# include root in json for array?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, json

rails 3: include_root_in_json = true allows to have a root property for json response. But it doesn't work with array of object, there is a property like include_root_in_array_json?
actually I have this response:

```
[ {"model": {"a":"a_value"}}, {"model": {"b":"b_value"}}]
```

but I want a response like that:

```
{"models":[ {"model": {"a":"a_value"}}, {"model": {"b":"b_value"}}]}
```

xml response has a root property 'models' which include the array, but json not...

Comment: Post some samples and expected outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
{models: Model.all}.to_json
```

It's not a very elegant solution but it does its job fine.