# How do I include the JSON root in an array when including associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

This is similar to [include root in json for array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750690/include-root-in-json-for-array), but slightly different.

I have an object Alpha with a has_many association to Beta. I'm rendering Alpha as JSON and want to include Beta.

```
@alpha.as_json(:include => :beta)
```

This works great, and since I have include_root_in_json set to true, the root of alpha is outputted.

```
{"alpha":
  {
    "created_at":"2012-06-07T23:37:30Z",
    "id":1,
    "beta":[
      {
        "created_at":"2012-06-11T23:46:58Z",
        "id":1,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to include the root in the beta array as well, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use RABL (https://github.com/nesquena/rabl). It provides better formatting control for JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `root` option to `true` for the association:

```
@alpha.as_json(:include => { :beta => { :root => true } })
```

Comment: I tried that, but I'll try again. Perhaps my brackets were off.

Comment: Depends whether you are using the Ruby 1.8 or 1.9 hash syntax. The example uses 1.8's, which would make `:root` correct. I wasn't sure if this would work, I just figured it was worth a shot. You might not actually be able to do this.